# How to do Django query to list all the first instances of a date?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Attendance(TimeStamped):
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    punch = models.DateTimeField()
```

The employee punches twice everyday, once to get in and once to log out.

I want to come up with a QuerySet so that I get only the PUNCH INs of the employee. I tried to use `distinct()` but can't get it to work.

So if an employee goes to office for two days I will have four rows in the model. But I want to only get two rows; only the first result of each date.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show your TimeStamped model?... If you want to distinguish between punch_in and punch_out, you add those field as Boolean and handle it by overriding the save method..

Comment: @FazilZaid They just have a `created` and `modified` field with `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` set to True respectively.

Comment: @FazilZaid I can't distinguish. The data is being imported from another device. It will be saved to this model. I have to pick the first entry of a day to be the log in and the last entry to be the log out.

Comment: Are there going to be multiple punching besides login and logout?? I am just clearing my doubts.. that's all

Comment: @FazilZaid Not that I know of. I'm building it with only two entries per employee per day.

Comment: I've added some code, let me know if anything comes up..

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to distinguish between login and logout then, you need to consider refactoring your models a bit like this..

```
class Attendance (TimeStamped):
    ..........................
    punch_in = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    punch_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            login = Attendance.objects.get(modified=self.modified)
            self.punch_out = True
            self.punch_in = False
        except Attendance​.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return super(Attendance, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you could do queries with,

```
   Attendance.objects.filter(modified=some_date, punch_in=True)
```

Assuming the instances aren't meant to be modified.
Or you would have to utilise the datetime.combine() , which would make the code more ugly.

I'd recommend to use models.DateField() for the modified field.The above code is under the assumption of the same.

Another option is to add a field similar to created field but of the type models.DateField() which is redundant.

Hope this would work for you..

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. I just created a list where the date is added. Then I added an if statement which confirms if the date is in the list or not. So the first time the date gets added, and second time it doesn't. And now it's working. I can't change the model for this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out yourself..!! Then the list would contain the whole instances of the punches ever made.. right?? If there are a 100 users, and 100 days, there would be 100 lists with 100 elements... Am I on the right track??

Comment: Yes. Correct. However, the days would only be 31 days highest.

Comment: Again, the list would be there for every month in the database right?? This kind  of redundancy can cause serious performance issues in the future.. Just a heads up though..

Comment: You are correct. I'm repopulating the list for every iteration of months. It's a small scale app, so I think performance wouldn't be an issue. Having a boolean field would've been better.